# UITableViewCell doesn't reuse

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my case, i have a customize tableview cell with a identifier, And in the TableViewControlelr has a method called `configCellAtIndexPath:` implemented like this:

```
configCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    XXCell *cell = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: identifier];
    // Config the cell
    return cell.
}
```

Both `- tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and `- tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` use the returned cell do the work.

The problem is When I scroll the tableview, the number of cell is increasing continues, for example, I have 20 items and there should at most 20 cell instance but there are 30+ Cell instance actually.

In addition, i adjust cell height during `configCellAtIndexPath:` and sometimes when a cell is about to show, there will be a obvious pause.

And idea about this?

Comment: How do you know that there are 30 cell instances? Are you storing reference to them in some other array?

Comment: Do you use a xib for your custom cell?

Comment: check: `-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` method whether this method returns more objects than it actually shows

Comment: @BrianTrzupek I know these by using Instruments, there are not any reference to these cell beside the calling method.

Comment: @Psykie No, I subclass the cell without using xib, and register the cell using 
`- registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` method, I did override `- initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` and does the necessary initialization.

Comment: @EbruGüngör I 'm sure that the number of object returned is corrected by using Instruments.

Comment: Did you register the good class  in the registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier: method? No error in your identifier? Maybe if you post all of your code, it could help.